# eloquent filter query by date in controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I have this eloquent function in my controller to return rows to my view , I want to limit  to filter by today's date
here is my function:

````
 $rows = \App\Models\WeightsJournalView::where(function($query) use($request){
                      $query->orwhere('id','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orwhere('currentAvgWeightMale','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orwhere('currentAvgWeightFemale','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orwhere('pastAvgWeightMale','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orwhere('pastAvgWeightFemale','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orwhere('batch_name','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orwhere('barn_name','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orwhere('farm_name','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orwhere('created_at','like',date('Y-m-d'));
                  })->orderBy($request['sort'],$request['order'])
                    ->skip($request['offset'])
                    ->take($request['limit'])
                    ->get();```
````

Comment: I want to use the function this way , just filtering the rows by today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
 orWhereBetween('created_at',[Carbon::now()->startOfDay(),\Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])
```

*\Carbon::now()->startOfDay()*   will give you the very beginning of today

*\Carbon::now()->endOfDay()* will give you the very ending of the day

or you can use:

```
orWhereDate('created_at',Carbon::now()->toDateString())
```

orWhereDate will take the only date part of dateTime column, and it value will be compared to date string of now.

Comment: Tried : 
orWhereDate('created_at',Carbon::now()->toDateString()) didnt return any rows

Comment: the first way .. returned any result?

Comment: no unfortunately , my original code only retunes all results,

Answer (score 0):

That should do it if I understood your problem correctly

````
 $rows = \App\Models\WeightsJournalView::whereDate('created_at', '=' , date('Y-m-d')) 
        ->andWhere(function ($query) {
                      $query->where('id','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orWhere('currentAvgWeightMale','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orWhere('currentAvgWeightFemale','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orWhere('pastAvgWeightMale','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orWhere('pastAvgWeightFemale','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orWhere('batch_name','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orWhere('barn_name','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orWhere('farm_name','like',$request['search'])
                      ->orWhere('created_at','like',date('Y-m-d'));
                  })->orderBy($request['sort'],$request['order'])
                    ->skip($request['offset'])
                    ->take($request['limit'])
                    ->get();```
````

Comment: ```                           $rows = \App\Models\WeightsJournalView::where('created_at','=',date('Y-m-d'))
                                   ->andWhere(function ($query)  use($request) {
                                                 $query->where('id','like',$request['search'])
                                                 -
```
I used like this but no rows returned

Comment: is your created_at column date or datetime?

Comment: it is date time (timestamp)

Comment: try whereDate('created_at', '=' , date('Y-m-d')) or whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())

Answer (score 0):

The first solution worked after I tweaked it like the following thanks Guys :

```
  $rows = \App\Models\WeightsJournalView::whereDate('created_at', '=' , date('Y-m-d'))
                                    ->Where(function ($query) use($request){
                                                  $query->where('id','like',$request['search'])
                                                  ->orWhere('currentAvgWeightMale','like',$request['search'])
                                                  ->orWhere('currentAvgWeightFemale','like',$request['search'])
                                                  ->orWhere('pastAvgWeightMale','like',$request['search'])
                                                  ->orWhere('pastAvgWeightFemale','like',$request['search'])
                                                  ->orWhere('batch_name','like',$request['search'])
                                                  ->orWhere('barn_name','like',$request['search'])
                                                  ->orWhere('farm_name','like',$request['search']);
                                              })->orderBy($request['sort'],$request['order'])
                                                ->skip($request['offset'])
                                                ->take($request['limit'])
                                                ->get();
```

Comment: sure did that but because I am low in rep it didn't recorded , the system says it is but I see it doesn't :)